# Visibility of toolbar items in Eclipse 4 model

Tags: eclipse, toolbar, eclipse-kepler, e4

I have a simple e4 RPC application, based on e4 model. I have two parts in PartSachContainer - left one and right one.
And I need a certain toolbar item to be visible when one part is active, and another item to be visible when another part is active.

I tried to use CoreExpression for this, but to no avail. I can't understand what do I need to write in the expression itself.

My config is as follows:

First part is defined as

```
ID: simple1.part.leftpart
Label: LeftPart
ClassURI: bundleclass://Simple1/simple1.parts.LeftPart
```

The second part is defined as

```
ID: simple1.part.rightpart
Label: RightPart
ClassURI: bundleclass://Simple1/simple1.parts.RightPart
```

The ToolBar Contribution is defined as

```
<toolBarContributions xmi:id="_gqB4gNaWEeO3iqh7a9kwnw" elementId="simple1.toolbarcontribution.0" parentId="simple1.toolbar.0">
    <children xsi:type="menu:HandledToolItem" xmi:id="_PtGaINaSEeO3iqh7a9kwnw" elementId="simple1.handledtoolitem.leftpitem" iconURI="platform:/plugin/Simple1/icons/sample.png" command="_vFvtcNaREeO3iqh7a9kwnw">
      <visibleWhen xsi:type="ui:CoreExpression" xmi:id="_z_87oNanEeO3iqh7a9kwnw" coreExpressionId="Simple1.RightPartActive"/>
    </children>
  </toolBarContributions>
```

When I set Visible-When Expression to  I can see the toolbar item.
But when I try to use CoreExpression (and I tried various combinations) I never see the toolbar item.

This is what I start with:

```
  <definition id="Simple1.RightPartActive">
     <with variable="activePartId">
        <equals 
              value="simple1.part.rightpart">
        </equals>
     </with>
  </definition>
```

No luck.

How should I define the CoreExpression to see the toolbar item?

And here's to the real problem:
This right part should really be an editor (in e3 terms) - the same implementaion class for multiple various instances of editable data. So, I will use the runtime-generated unique IDs for this parts (the parts themleves would be created from PartDescription).
So how should I address these parts with generated IDs in CoreExpression?

**UPDATE**

Ok, I did some debugging and found out that there is a method

```
public EvaluationResult evaluate(IEvaluationContext context)
```

of the class 
*org.eclipse.core.internal.expressions.WithExpression*
that is being called.

The very first line :

```
Object variable= context.getVariable(fVariable);
```

calls method of the class *EclipseContext*

```
public Object getVariable(String name) {
    if (IEclipseContext.class.getName().equals(name)) {
    return eclipseContext;
    }
    Object obj = eclipseContext.getActive(name);
    return obj == null ? IEvaluationContext.UNDEFINED_VARIABLE : obj;
}
```

where

```
public Object getActive(final String name) {
    return getActiveLeaf().get(name);
}
```

and

```
public IEclipseContext getActiveLeaf() {
    IEclipseContext activeContext = this;
    IEclipseContext child = getActiveChild();
    while (child != null) {
        activeContext = child;
    child = child.getActiveChild();
    }
    return activeContext;
}
```

and [b]activeChild[/b] is always null.

And I don't see anything in EclipseContext which would be something like "activePartId" or anything close to it.

So why is it so??
How can we even use the CoreExpressions??

Comment: Maybe another option would be to place the buttons in the tool bar of the parts (not in the application tool bar)?

Comment: That could be done, yes.
But it doesn't look as good as in the main tool bar. Can be confusing for the user.
And I also have some eclipse 3 application which used editor contributions, and I might need to migrate them to new architecture.
But your suggestions is still valid, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like Eclipse bug [400217](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=400217), which is saying that this does not currently work.

Comment: Well, it may be it, thanks.

But am I doing everything right? No obvious errors?

And what about the "real problem" - what would I do if there was no such bug?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're in e4 why not handle it the e4 way ?

```
Subscribe to the UIEvents.UILifeCycle.ACTIVATE event.
if (newActivePart == LeftPart)
  <set 'toBeRendered' to true for LeftPart's items and false for RightPart's items
```

same for Right part...

Comment: could you please elaborate?
When I use  
  
`@Inject
// private void getNotified(@UIEventTopic(UIEvents.UILifeCycle.ACTIVATE) Object event)`  
  
I always get null in event.

Comment: I expect that the signature should contain the osgi 'Event' rather than 'Object'. Lars Vogel has some excellent blogs on this...